# получить url страницы с которой перешли

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 2 страницы A.html и B.html
На странице A есть ссылка `<a href="B.html>B</a>`

Пытаюсь в лог вывести url `console.log(document.referrer)` но получаю пустую строку. `console.log(document)` возвращает #document.

Когда делаю тоже самое но с использованием web-сервера, показывает нужный путь.
console.log(document) -> [object HTMLDocument]
 В чем подвох? Как использовать без web-сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что referrer - это один из http-заголовков, который передается из браузера на сервер, чтобы сообщить, на какой странице пользователь находился перед тем, как перешел на Вашу. Так что сервер - необходимая составляющая этого процесса.

[Подробнее об http-заголовках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP)